# How to Hide Sign in Link from Header Component (after logged in) in angular 2?

Tags: angular, authentication

My header is common for login page and dashboard page how to hide the Sign in Link from Header Component (after logged in) and show the user profile dropdown in angular 2

Comment: @RahulSingh i tried with *ngif for the login link and changing the value by false from calling a function after login conditions true.. By that value is changed to false but the link was not hide... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you logged in create a cookies, local storage or session storage. youcan refer my code below

```
     this.services.checkUserDetails(this.userInfo.userId, this.userInfo.password).subscribe(
            data => {
                if (data.status === true) {
                    localStorage.setItem('X-Auth-Token', data.data.token); //stored data in browser
                    console.log(data);
                    localStorage.setItem("userId", "1"); //stored data in browser
 }
                else {
                    this.errorMessage = data.errorMessage;
                    this.utils.stopLoading();
                }
            },
            error => {
                this.errorMessage = error.errorMessage;
                this.utils.toast("error", error);
                this.utils.stopLoading();
            });
```

My Header component i have used like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
if (localStorage.getItem('X-Auth-Token') == null) {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
else {
  this.id = localStorage.getItem("userId");     //**Retried data**  
  this.name = localStorage.getItem("userName");
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks! @shanmugapriya It works but after refresh only the condition was checking if any chance to check the condition without refreshing the page??

Comment: where ever you want you can use this line                                                
 if (localStorage.getItem('X-Auth-Token') == null) {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
else {
  this.id = localStorage.getItem("userId");     //**Retried data**  
  this.name = localStorage.getItem("userName");
}

Comment: This is ok but i use this code to hide and show the sign in link in header for this condition page is not to be refreshed

Comment: Can u help me in the SEO also in angular 2?

Comment: SEO for what can u tell me briefly

Comment: How to check view source in angular 2 and how to index my website in google?

Answer (score 1):

Create a global service that holds the user object

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  let user;

  setUser(user) { this.user = user }
  isLoggedIn() { return this.user }
}
```